# ContentPresenter.Content slow rendering first time only

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, rendering

I'm working on a flipbook App, where user can swipe on pages, or press buttons to turn page left or right. After each successful animation event is raised in order to set the new content to the newly displayed pages. This however has a 1-2 secs delay only the first time that specific page is loaded, every other time it works flawlessly. Here is the code that's causing this weird delay:

```
if (_currentSheetIndex == 0)
{
    sheet0Page0Content.Content = null;
    sheet0Page1Content.Content = null;
    sheet0Page2Content.Content = null;
}
else
{
    sheet0Page0Content.Content = GetPage(2 * (CurrentSheetIndex - 1) + 1);
    sheet0Page1Content.Content = GetPage(2 * (CurrentSheetIndex - 1));
    sheet0Page2Content.Content = GetPage(2 * (CurrentSheetIndex - 1) - 1);
}

sheet1Page0Content.Content = GetPage(2 * CurrentSheetIndex);
sheet1Page1Content.Content = GetPage(2 * CurrentSheetIndex + 1);
sheet1Page2Content.Content = GetPage(2 * CurrentSheetIndex + 2);

internal object GetPage(int index)
{
    if ((index >= 0) && (index < Items.Count))
        return Items[index];

    Canvas c = new Canvas();

    return c;
}
```

sheet0Page0Content and others are type ContentPresenter. Items are UserControls that are used to display content to book pages. I tried searching about various rendering types and virtualization, thinking that the problem may be related to slow rendering, but with no luck. Any ideas on this?

Comment: you could add a progress ring entertaining user at first load?

Comment: I'm looking for a root cause of the problem. I could implement a solution like you suggested, but I'd rather know why this is happening.

Comment: What about profiling your code?